# How to disable spell check for a single line (with a custom tag)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, spell-checking, filetype-markdown

Sometimes I do not want to add words to a spellfile, but still ignore them this *once*. This is particularly prevalent when I write *markdown*.

It would be nice if I could tag a line with `<!-- nospell -->` (akin to telling a linter to ignore that line) to have it be ignored by the spell checker.

I suspect the answer will have something to do with `@NoSpell` and `.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` but I'm not familiar enough with syntax highlighting to compose this myself.

PS: I use [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/preservim/vim-markdown) plugin, but I don't think this should matter.

Comment: I feel bad for posting an answer that has obvious downsides and then never getting around to coming up with a full solution when you pointed these out. Until I do, I'm deleting my answer so your question comes up in the "Unanswered" section again: hopefully someone with more time or expertise will write a proper solution.